# Pop up window triggers if i run process with administrative privillage c#

Tags: c#, cmd

As I want to run the `cmd` with administrative privilege in the process, but the pop up open up even set the `WindowStyle` to hidden.

```
 ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + @"cscript.exe DTCSECURITY.vbs");
 ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;.
 ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

 // Here with i pass the privillage
 ProcessInfo.UserName = @"administrator";
 ProcessInfo.Password = StringToSecureString("password12$");    

 process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
 process.WaitForExit();
```

But if I comment the privillage code no pop up blinks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set [`WorkingDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) property. From *MSDN*;

> The WorkingDirectory property must be set if UserName and Password are
>   provided. If the property is not set, the default working directory is
>   %SYSTEMROOT%\system32.

---

> If the UserName property is not null or an empty string, the
>   UseShellExecute property must be false, or an
>   InvalidOperationException will be thrown when the
>   Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo) method is called.

Comment: I tried whatever you suggested, still attempt the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute` to `false` (it is `true` by default).

[ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx) says:

> If the UseShellExecute property is true or the UserName and Password
>   properties are not null, the CreateNoWindow property value is ignored
>   and a new window is created.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is pop up hidden if not set the privilege. if i pass, then pop up comes automatically

Comment: even if you add `ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;`?